# The user object is empty in app even though it is returned from backend server

Tags: react-native

Here is an _onPress in my react native app. The purpose of this function is to retrieve the user object and pass it to the next component after the user clicks an item. `async/await` is used for the db retrieval in `_getUser`. I can see the user object on the server but `myself` receives nothing and is empty. I am not sure why the `myself` is empty. Should `_getUser` be called in the constructor instead?

```
async _onPress(id) {
      let myself = await _getUser();
      if (!myself) console.log("_getUser return nothing in Chat!"); 
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat", {eventId: id, user: myself});
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't _getUser be `this. _getUser ()` ? maybe thats why your myself is always empty as which you can confirm why surrounding it with try catch and print the error

Comment: `this` did not work. I tried before post and it caused error.

Comment: Probably _getUser() should go into the componentDidMount with `user` as `state`.

Comment: can you tell where are you calling this `_onPress` function from ? if you are directly calling from onPress of  something line `TouchableOpacity` and `_getUser()` is promise i suggest you go with `.then()` approach

Comment: I moved the `getUser()` into componentDidMount as async and assign the res to a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As _getUser() is returning promise and probably `_onPress` is getting called directly from ToucableOpacity or some touch responder button, you can resolve promise and then take necessary action like:

```
_onPress(id) {
  _getUser()
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        console.log("_getUser return nothing in Chat!");
        return
      }
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat", { eventId: id, user: data });
    })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
}
```

Comment: I moved the `getUser()` into componentDidMount as async and assign the res to a state.